# Exposing qml Object to Website/Javascript using QWebChannel

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I would like to display a custom input device on a touchscreen as soon as a html input field gets focused within the displaying [QWebEngineView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtwebengine-webengineview.html). Therefore I tried to expose the input device object via [QWebChannel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebchannel-javascript.html) to the client side Javascipt, which could then invoke the show method of the input device as soon as an input field gets focused.

However, currently I get one of the following two errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined at line 60
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: QWebChannel is not defined at line 2

Furthermore I am not sure when to use *navigator.qtWebChannelTransport* instead of *qt.webChannelTransport* as parameter for QWebChannel.

**Window.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow {

    WebView {
        id: webView
        anchors.fill: parent

        // Register keyboard as web channel object.
        webChannel.registeredObjects: [myObject]
    }

    MyObject {
        id: myObject
        WebChannel.id: "myWebObject"
    }
}
```

**WebView.qml**

```
WebEngineView {

    // Load web channel and input method handling scripts.
    userScripts: [
        WebEngineScript {
            injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentCreation
            name: "QWebChannel"
            sourceUrl: "qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"
        },

        WebEngineScript {
            injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentReady
            name: "MyObjectInjector"
            sourceUrl: "qrc:/myscript.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

**myscript.js**

```
window.channel = new QWebChannel(navigator.qtWebChannelTransport, function(channel) {
    var inputs = window.document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT');

    var index;
    for(index=0; index < inputs.length; index++) {
        inputs[index].onfocus = function() {
            console.log("Input focused");
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> Uncaught ReferenceError: QWebChannel is not defined at line 2

I guess QWebChannel is not exposed to myscript.js. Try `worldId: WebEngineScript.MainWorld` in WebEngineScript.

```
    WebEngineScript {
        injectionPoint: WebEngineScript.DocumentCreation
        worldId: WebEngineScript.MainWorld
        name: "QWebChannel"
        sourceUrl: "qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js"
    },
```

> Furthermore I am not sure when to use navigator.qtWebChannelTransport instead of qt.webChannelTransport as parameter for QWebChannel.

`qt.webChannelTransport` seems to be correct. See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-52090.