# Uncaught ReferenceError: QWebChannel is not defined

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

i have a  QWebEngineView that load a page like http://google.com and i want to load my keyboard to input boxes so i should use QWebChannel and WebEngineScript.
i do all the thing for webchannel :import QtWebChannel 1.0 ,QT += webchannel in .pro
, #include  in main.cpp and i use [Exposing qml Object to Website/Javascript using QWebChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849541/exposing-qml-object-to-website-javascript-using-qwebchannel)
 but  i got the error  js: Uncaught ReferenceError: QWebChannel is not defined....
i am using Qt 5.9.1

```
window.channel = new QWebChannel(qt.webChannelTransport, function(channel)
```

this new don't work and i think it's because javascript file "qrc:///qtwebchannel/qwebchannel.js" do not exist , how  can i fix it?

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for interested people:

as i thought the problem was`qwebchannel.js` that it didn't exist(i don't know why) so i found it and copy it to my javascript file then the problem solved but i got the problem that `qt is not defined` and after a lot search i understood that `qwebengine` works with objects just .
i hope it helps someone